# Xamarin forms - iOS HealthKit user permission problem for Health Clinical Record. Authorisation disallowed

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, healthkit

Trying to setup healthkit permissions for accessing/reading user's health record clinical data like allergies and conditions etc.

Following article and translating for Xamarin.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/samples/accessing_a_user_s_clinical_records

The following code is not working and giving me the error.

```
NSSet HealthRecordDataTypesToRead
        {
            get
            {
                return NSSet.MakeNSObjectSet<HKSampleType>(new HKSampleType[] {

                

                //Clinical Record 
                HKObjectType.GetClinicalType(HKClinicalTypeIdentifier.ConditionRecord),
                HKObjectType.GetClinicalType(HKClinicalTypeIdentifier.AllergyRecord),
                HKObjectType.GetClinicalType(HKClinicalTypeIdentifier.MedicationRecord),
                HKObjectType.GetClinicalType(HKClinicalTypeIdentifier.ProcedureRecord),
                HKObjectType.GetClinicalType(HKClinicalTypeIdentifier.LabResultRecord),
                HKObjectType.GetClinicalType(HKClinicalTypeIdentifier.ImmunizationRecord),
                HKObjectType.GetClinicalType(HKClinicalTypeIdentifier.VitalSignRecord),

            });
            }
        }
var (ishrAllowed, hrerror) = await HealthStore.RequestAuthorizationToShareAsync(new NSSet(), HealthRecordDataTypesToRead);
                if (hrerror != null)
                    throw new Exception($"There is an error during permssion request. Error Description: {error.LocalizedDescription}");
                result = ishrAllowed;
```

**Error**

Foundation.MonoTouchException: Objective-C exception thrown.  Name: NSInvalidArgumentException Reason: Authorization to read the following types is disallowed: HKClinicalTypeIdentifierMedicationRecord, HKClinicalTypeIdentifierConditionRecord, HKClinicalTypeIdentifierProcedureRecord, HKClinicalTypeIdentifierVitalSignRecord, HKClinicalTypeIdentifierImmunizationRecord, HKClinicalTypeIdentifierAllergyRecord, HKClinicalTypeIdentifierLabResultRecord
Native stack trace:
\t0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff2043a126 __exceptionPreprocess + 242
\t1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff20177f78 objc_exception_throw + 48
\t2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff2043a004 -[NSException initWithCoder:] + 0
\t3   HealthKit                           0x00007fff35315e22 -[HKHealthStore _throwIfAuthorizationDisallowedForSharing:types:] + 534
\t4   HealthKit                           0x00007fff35314a4b -[HKHealthStore _validateAuthorizationRequestWithShareTypes:readTypes:] + 224
\t5   HealthKit                           0x00007fff35314bca -[HKHealthStore requestAuthorizationToShareTypes:readTypes:shouldPrompt:completion:] + 336
\t6   HealthKit                           0x00007fff35314948 -[HKHealthStore requestAuthorizationToShareTypes:readTypes:completion:] + 77
\t7   Health.iOS                       0x000000010663b969 xamarin_dyn_objc_msgSend + 217
\t8   ???                                 0x000000011abad00b 0x0 + 4743417867

at ObjCRuntime.Runtime.ThrowNSException (System.IntPtr ns_exception) [0x00000] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/14.4.1.3/src/Xamarin.iOS/ObjCRuntime/Runtime.cs:407 
at ObjCRuntime.Runtime.throw_ns_exception (System.IntPtr exc) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-macios/xamarin-macios/runtime/Delegates.generated.cs:126 
at (wrapper native-to-managed) ObjCRuntime.Runtime.throw_ns_exception(intptr)
at (wrapper managed-to-native) ObjCRuntime.Messaging.void_objc_msgSend_IntPtr_IntPtr_IntPtr(intptr,intptr,intptr,intptr,intptr)
at HealthKit.HKHealthStore.RequestAuthorizationToShare (Foundation.NSSet typesToShare, Foundation.NSSet typesToRead, System.Action`2[T1,T2] completion) [0x0002f] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/14.4.1.3/src/Xamarin.iOS/HealthKit/HKHealthStore.g.cs:619 \ at HealthKit.HKHealthStore.RequestAuthorizationToShareAsync (Foundation.NSSet typesToShare, Foundation.NSSet typesToRead) [0x00011] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/14.4.1.3/src/Xamarin.iOS/HealthKit/HKHealthStore.g.cs:631 \ at Health.iOS.DependencyService.HealthKitData.GetHealthPermissionAsync () [0x0014f] in C:\\\\Repos\\\\Health.Master\\\\Mobile\\\\Health.iOS\\\\DependencyServices\\\\HealthKitData.cs:322 \ at (wrapper managed-to-native) ObjCRuntime.Messaging.void_objc_msgSend_IntPtr_IntPtr_IntPtr(intptr,intptr,intptr,intptr,intptr)\ at HealthKit.HKHealthStore.RequestAuthorizationToShare (Foundation.NSSet typesToShare, Foundation.NSSet typesToRead, System.Action`2[T1,T2] completion) [0x0002f] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/14.4.1.3/src/Xamarin.iOS/HealthKit/HKHealthStore.g.cs:619 
at HealthKit.HKHealthStore.RequestAuthorizationToShareAsync (Foundation.NSSet typesToShare, Foundation.NSSet typesToRead) [0x00011] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/14.4.1.3/src/Xamarin.iOS/HealthKit/HKHealthStore.g.cs:631 
at Health.iOS.DependencyService.HealthKitData.GetHealthPermissionAsync () [0x0014f] in C:\\Repos\\Health.Master\\Mobile\\Health.iOS\\DependencyServices\\HealthKitData.cs:322 
at Health.Core.ViewModels.Trackers.TrackerListMenuViewModel.ProcessTrackerSelection (Health.Core.Helpers.Ui.UiDataItem selectedItem, System.Boolean saveDeviceChanges) [0x001b5] in C:\\Repos\\Health.Master\\Mobile\\Health.Core\\ViewModels\\Trackers\\TrackerListMenuViewModel.cs:304 \t0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff2043a126 __exceptionPreprocess + 242
\t1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff20177f78 objc_exception_throw + 48
\t2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff2043a004 -[NSException initWithCoder:] + 0
\t3   HealthKit                           0x00007fff35315e22 -[HKHealthStore _throwIfAuthorizationDisallowedForSharing:types:] + 534
\t4   HealthKit                           0x00007fff35314a4b -[HKHealthStore _validateAuthorizationRequestWithShareTypes:readTypes:] + 224
\t5   HealthKit                           0x00007fff35314bca -[HKHealthStore requestAuthorizationToShareTypes:readTypes:shouldPrompt:completion:] + 336
\t6   HealthKit                           0x00007fff35314948 -[HKHealthStore requestAuthorizationToShareTypes:readTypes:completion:] + 77
\t7   Health.iOS                       0x000000010663b969 xamarin_dyn_objc_msgSend + 217
\t8   ???                                 0x000000011abad00b 0x0 + 4743417867\

** info.plist entries **

````
        <string>Health App needs Health Share Access</string>
        <key>NSHealthUpdateUsageDescription</key>
        <string>Health App needs Health Update Access</string>      
    <key>NSHealthRequiredReadAuthorizationTypeIdentifiers</key>
    <array>
      <string>HKClinicalTypeIdentifierAllergyRecord</string>
      <string>HKClinicalTypeIdentifierConditionRecord</string>
      <string>HKClinicalTypeIdentifierImmunizationRecord</string>
      <string>HKClinicalTypeIdentifierLabResultRecord</string>
      <string>HKClinicalTypeIdentifierMedicationRecord</string>
      <string>HKClinicalTypeIdentifierProcedureRecord</string>
      <string>HKClinicalTypeIdentifierVitalSignRecord</string>
    </array>
    <key>NSHealthClinicalHealthRecordsShareUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Health App needs your clinical Health Record Access</string> ```
````

Comment: Have you added the required `Info.plist` entries?

Comment: Yes. I have. The question is updated.

Comment: You could refer to the official doc [HealthKit in Xamarin.iOS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/platform/healthkit).

Comment: Thanks Leo. There is hardly anything available related to the error/exception I am getting.

Comment: Did you follow the instructions in the documentation?

Comment: Compare the documentation again with your source code. You are missing one method and placed one non-null argument.

Comment: ic... I will try... If you could point out, it would be little help thanks in advance.

Comment: There is nothing in documentation regarding issue of Clinical Health Record Permissions I am facing.